# How to avoid a specific css file to apply on my Component in Angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular12

I'm currently using bootstrap for my modal component but our current project has a css file that is using the same class with bootstrap (.Modal,.Modal-header).

The css styling of both files was messing the modal design.

Any solution for this?

**Update**

I use `::ng-deep` to my css so I can specifically target without conflicting other css file.

Comment: simply remove `.Modal,.Modal-header` from your css file.

Comment: I can't do that, it might break some part of our application.

Comment: then what you want to achieve. be clear

Comment: change the class name or overwrite the styles for the desired class name by selecting its parent component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use Bootstrap components in your class. If this was not helpful, please check ask from https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry or  https://stackoverflow.com/users/8213994/aman-gojariya. They helped me too.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap 5. It has new features and more.